# How to find the max value per group in NDB

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm used python with ndb in my app.
How to find the max value per group in NDB?

My table

```
user_id | level_number | score
--------+--------------+--------------------
      1 | 1            | 15
      1 | 1            | 5
      1 | 2            | 26
      1 | 2            | 30
```

I want to get max score each level

Comment: Guess you'll need to write some code. Since you haven't told us anything about what a "group" is, what the value might be, or anything else about your problem, we can't help any further than that.

Comment: Does ndb has max() method like mysql?

Comment: `Does ndb has max() method like mysql?` Nope. You can [order](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass#Query_order) a query result, though, which can give you similar behavior. Or [you can do](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#computed) a `ComputedProperty` that pre-calculates a max or a value and then query for it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the best would be to do a query with a sort order on the score where level_number = 1, then 2, then 3.  Since the datastore cannot do computations, you'll need to use the sorting and just keep the highest one, if you don't want to do computations in your code.

I would personally have the scores linked to a parent entity "level", and then query per ancestor and check the highest score.