# How to arrive at the max value for a field with Google App Engine NDB

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

This similar [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25241274/how-to-find-the-max-value-per-group-in-ndb) except that this is for NDB and is up to date. NDB does not have the `Limit` attribute.

The question is how do you arrive at the max value for a field in using Google App Engine NDB? This is to essentially replicate the max functions found in SQL languages like TSQL, PLSQL, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippet is like this:

```
max_of_the_field = Kind.query().order(-Kind.the_field).fetch(1)
```

`Kind` is to be replaced with your kind name. As you may know, kinds are roughly analogous to SQL tables and Entities are records.

Note the minus (-) sign at the beginning of the parameters for `order`. This means descending. Then the `.fetch(1)` says "just get me the first record." The descending order along with the .fetch(1) yields the maximum value of the field.

`max_of_the_field` is provided to make this look more like a complete line of code. You may, of course, be using this differently.

`the_field` will need to be indexed, which is beyond the scope of this answer.

There are potential scalability and cost issues with large numbers of entities. Others have suggested tracking what your max is in some sort of a look up kind as records are added / updated.